# Laravel Factory Logic

Tags: php, laravel, factory

I have the factory below. When I set it to create more than one model, the ID does not seem to increment. Please help me understand how I can make this code work so the ID increments each time.

```php
<?php

/* @var $factory \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory */

use App\PurchaseOrder;
use Faker\Generator as Faker;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

$factory->define(PurchaseOrder::class, function (Faker $faker) {

    DB::select(DB::raw('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0'));
    $numberOfLines = rand(1, 5);
    $id = PurchaseOrder::all()->last()->id + 1?? 1;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $numberOfLines; $i++) {
        $line = factory(App\Line::class)->make([
            'purchase_order_id' => $id,
        ]);
        $line->save();
    };

    $lines = App\Line::where('purchase_order_id', $id)->get();
    DB::select(DB::raw('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1'));
    return [
        'total_price_ex_vat' => $lines->sum('price_ex_vat'),
        'total_price_inc_vat' => $lines->sum('price_inc_vat'),
        'revised_total_price_ex_vat' => $lines->sum('revised_price_ex_vat'),
        'revised_total_price_inc_vat' => $lines->sum('revised_price_inc_vat'),
        'deliver_to' => $faker->words(2, true),
        'requested_staff_id' => factory(App\Staff::class)->create()->id ,
        'auth_staff_id' => Null,
        'supplier_id' => factory(App\Supplier::class)->create()->id,
        'rejection_code_id' => Null,
        'status_id' => 1,
        'status_changed_date' => date('Y-m-d'),
        'user_id' => factory(App\User::class)->create()->id,
    ];

});
```

Comment: Is `purchase_order_id` your primary key or `id`?

Comment: @glenuk its better you should show us the migration of that table too.

Comment: @RashedHasan sorry, I pasted the wrong factory. It should make more sense now.

Comment: @JGEscarilla sorry, I pasted the wrong factory. It should make more sense now.

Comment: I believe you shouldn't create the Line first. My suggestion:
1. First create the PurchaseOrder
2. Use the afterCreating (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database-testing#factory-callbacks) and in this method you create the lines

This way you can also remove the FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS line

Comment: @MauroBaptista I want to create the Lines second; however, I need values from the Lines to populate the PurchaseOrder.

Comment: You have table PurchaseOrder dependent on Lines, and Lines dependent on PurchaseOrder. I believe you should review your db design then, as this seems quite weird.
Why don't you avoid to use Lines in PurchaseOrder and load it as an attribute inside the PurchaseOrder model with an accessor?

Comment: @MauroBaptista I believe this is a good response and very helpful. If you would like to resubmit this as an answer, I will be happy to accept. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have table PurchaseOrder dependent on Lines, and Lines dependent on PurchaseOrder. I believe you should review your db design then, as this seems quite weird.

Why don't you avoid to use Lines in PurchaseOrder and load it as an attribute inside the PurchaseOrder model with an accessor?

For more info: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor